# Missing animation when calling setEditing:animated: to delete cells from table view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When deleting cells it calls my setEditing:animated: method which i have overridden because I need to adjust the height of my cells when editing, but because of this when I press the edit button the slide in animation of the red circles with the minus signs don't occur, instead they just appear into the cell. How Can I fix this?

This is my setEditing:animated code at the moment

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
[self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];

[self.tableView reloadData];

[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
```

}

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is in the reloadData call, is there any reason you're doing it? Maybe try calling it with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: so that it happens after the animation is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a reload call just for this purpose.  Try:

```
   - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    }
```

Comment: This affects only the new created rows, but rows that already created doesn't being affect.

Comment: Actually, it should only affect the currently visible cells (and there aren't any new ones being created here). Try NSLog(@"indexPaths = %@",[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]); to see if this is being called and if there are any cells visible at the time.

Comment: If I have one item in my list, on iOS8 this causes the cell to 'bounce' up and down during the animation! odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [self.tblView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(onLoadTable) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
-(void) onLoadTable
{
    [self.tblView reloadData];
}
```